# Camel XSD validation not working: Camel 2.12.1 / JBoss 5.1.0.GA / JDK 1.6

Tags: jboss, apache-camel

Camel validation is not working when i deploy to jboss, work perfectly with `mvn jetty:run`. See error below:

```
Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Source parameter of type 'org.apache.camel.StringSource' is not compatible with result parameter of type 'javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult'.
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.StreamValidatorHelper.validate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.ValidatorImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.validation.ValidatingProcessor.doProcess(ValidatingProcessor.java:152)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.validation.ValidatingProcessor.process(ValidatingProcessor.java:87)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:105)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.validation.ValidatingProcessor.process(ValidatingProcessor.java:82)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProcessorEndpoint.onExchange(ProcessorEndpoint.java:103)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProcessorEndpoint$1.process(ProcessorEndpoint.java:71)
....
```

Camel Route configuration below:

```xml
<camel:route id="process-xml-file" startupOrder="200">
    <from uri="direct:process-xml-file"/>
    <log message="processing file ${file:name}"/>
    <choice>
        <when>
            <xpath>/invoices/@region='regionA'</xpath>
            <split streaming="true" parallelProcessing="true">
                <tokenize token="invoice" inheritNamespaceTagName="dataexport" xml="true"/>
                <doTry>
                    <to uri="validator:xml/invoice.xsd"/>
                    <to uri="processInv"/>
                    <doCatch>
                        <exception>org.apache.camel.ValidationException</exception>
                        <exception>java.sql.SQLException</exception>
                        <setBody>
                            <simple>${exception.message}\n${body}</simple>
                        </setBody>
                        <to uri="direct:error-notification"/>
                    </doCatch>
                </doTry>
            </split>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <log message="ignoring file ${file:name}, not 'invoice'"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</camel:route>
```

Comment: I just did a simple test by using the StringSource message body within stand alone camel route, I cannot reproduce the error. From the stack trace it look more like the JAXP issue, can you just run the application without using JBoss?

Comment: Yes. `... not working when i deploy to jboss, work perfectly with mvn jetty:run`

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the code of 
[org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.StreamValidatorHelper](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.apache.xerces/com.springsource.org.apache.xerces/2.9.1/org/apache/xerces/jaxp/validation/StreamValidatorHelper.java#StreamValidatorHelper.validate%28javax.xml.transform.Source,javax.xml.transform.Result%29) and found out we can solve this issue by not setting the result type when call the validate method.
So I fill a [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7036) in camel to track this issue, you can fix this issue by porting the patch or using the latest snapshot which includes the patch

Comment: Validation works(both standalone and JBoss) if I use `xpath` to split the XML, i.e. replace line `<tokenize token="invoice" inheritNamespaceTagName="dataexport" xml="true"/>` with `<xpath>/invoices/invoive</xpath>`. I suspect the issue is the type of result returned by the `split` to the `validator`. I would prefer using `tokenize` after reading this: http://www.davsclaus.com/2011/11/splitting-big-xml-files-with-apache.html